# To write the reason for exception in excel

Tags: automated-testing, selenium-webdriver, java, appium

I'm using [Apache POI](https://poi.apache.org/) for `Excel` operation.

I'm able to print what exception it is in Excel by writing a print statement in that particular `catch()` block.

But I also want the reason for that `exception`, like if there is `elementNotFoundException`, then it should show particular `ID/xpath`/...is not found.

So, if this is possible, then how to do this ?

Answer (score 1):

Great, **When you are able to print stack stress or particular catch block() you will get particular ID/Xpath which is not found**

- You just need to again **add smartness using that print statement**
- **Find all exception and accordingly you can write method** as you wanted particular ID,XPATH or name

Answer (score 0):

You can write following thing in your catch statement

```
try {
...
...
// Your code
} catch (Exception | AssertionError error) {
.....
.....
// Your code
throw error;
}
```

Here we are catching 2 types of exceptions `Exception` and `AssertionError` that error gets stored in error variable and we are throwing the error which was caught after all your actions are performed in catch block